# Jquery appending issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON object which I loop through and works correct

```
iGenerateChilds = function (obj, div, $new) {
            var $new = $();
                $.each(obj.objects, function (p, par) {
                    $(div).append(iGenerateObject(par, ""));
                    alert(par.objects.length);
                    if (par.objects.length != 0) {
                        iGenerateChilds(par, div, $new);
                    }
                });
            return div;
        };
```

With this I want to approach that the objects are getting attached to each other, which it now does, however wrong and can't manage to figure out how to do this correct.

Currently it generates

```
<table></table><tr></tr><td></td><td></td>
```

and I want

```
<table><tr><td></td><td></td></tr></table>
```

Somebody has the solution on this?

Comment: May we have a sample JSON?

Comment: You're appending to the div, not the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
iGenerateChilds = function (obj, div) {
                $.each(obj.objects, function (p, par) {
                    var genObj = iGenerateObject(par, "");
                    $(div).append(genObj);
                    alert(par.objects.length);
                    if (par.objects.length != 0) {
                        // add the children to the newly added genObj-element
                        iGenerateChilds(par, genObj);
                    }
                });
            return div;
        };
```

Comment: Works like a sunshine )))) should stop working 12 hours a day ), thx!!

Comment: Somehow it adds the upvotes, but shows as downvote, think a mistake in the system, DID NOT DOWNVOTE!

Comment: Please try to fix this, also at the question of J.C (if you also did this). Thank you

Answer (score -1):

If you could post more information, like your HTML structure and your JSON object, that'd be helpful.

But at first glance I'd say that you're appending the elements at too high of a level. With this line `$(div).append(iGenerateObject(par, ""));` It looks like you're appending it to the element that's wraps your table, correct? It needs to be appended to the `<table>` within that passed element.